# Ubuntu 22.04 Server will not play mp4 Files from Samba File Share

Tags: apache2, samba

I have a Web Server running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  The Server will not play mp4 file that are mount by a samba file shares from a TrueNAS server.   The mount point exists on server but when I open up Dev Tools in a browser it giving a 404 Not Found error in the Network tab of Dev tools.  I have install openh264 codec on server with no help.   I have a Development Server that running Fedora 39 it will play the file just fine.  I had to set a sebool named httpd_use_cifs to on to let apache2 play the videos.  Just wondering if it something to do with apparmor.   Please help?

Comment: This may have something to do with the Apache configuration file as well. If you do not have a `<Directory>` section for the mount location, Apache will not allow software to read data from that location 

Comment: What does your server logs show?